# How to do per node caching in a tree visitor

Tags: c++, caching, c++11, visitor-pattern

I have an application where a want to calculate different representations (mesh, voxelization, signed distance function, ...) of a tree of primitives (leaf nodes) that are combined via boolean operations (inner nodes).

My first approach to this was to write an abstract base class with a virtual getter function for each of the different representations and cached the intermediate results at the respective nodes as long as there was no change in their subtree (which would flush their cache).

However, I was unsatisfied with the ugly coupling of the tree structure with each of the different representations. To alleviate this I removed the abstract base classes and instead set up a visitor for each of the representations.

This neatly decoupled the tree from the representations but left me with the problem that I now need to cache the intermediate results somewhere else and this is where my problem starts.

### TL;DR

How do I cache (arbitrary many differently typed) intermediate values at inner nodes of the tree without making the tree dependent on the value type?

### My Approaches

The requirements offer two choices:

- store the data in the tree but with type erasure
- store the data outside the tree and somehow "connect" it to the node

The first one leaves me puzzled with some efficiency problem: I could easily add a container of `boost::any` (or something equivalent) in the nodes but then each visitor would have to search the whole container for it's own data.

The separation in the second one introduces the problem of keeping the cache up to date to the current tree. If there are changes in the tree (deletions, alterations of nodes) the cached values must at least be invalidated. My intuition was to use some hash function and an `unordered_map` but I hit some problems there as well:

- I cannot use the treenodes themselves as key, so I need to introduce another class that just references tree nodes and represents them in the tree
- referencing the values from the `unordered_map`'s keys requires to erase all entries whose referencees are deleted or we have a dangling reference(/pointer) in the `unordered_map` which could get triggered on rehash
- changes in the tree would require to reconstruct the `unordered_map` because keys might have changed

Am I missing some obvious solution to this?
Which approach would you favor (and why)?

Answer (score 2):

I once had a similar problem and my solution was as follows:

1. Let each node have an unique identifier.
2. Let each node have a version number. Modifications that invalidate calculated values for the node just increase the version number.
3. Let each visitor have a caching map, where the ID pair is the key, mapped to a version/value pair.
4. When (re-)walking the tree, look for a node's entry in the map. If the version is correct, use the cached value. If it is outdated, calculate the new value and replace the old version/value pair.

At first, I used the node's address as IDs, but for memory reasons I had to reuse subtrees and picked the path to the node as ID. Such a path has the advantage that it can be calculated by each visitor and need not be stored at the node. In my case, each node could have at most two children, so a path was merely a set of left/right decisions, which can be stored in a simple unsigned int with some bit-shifting (my trees did never reach a depth of 32, so a 32 bit unsigned was more than enough as key).

Comment: Note: regarding the version number increase, it's important that if a node version increase, the version of its parent increase, etc... up to the root.

Comment: That depends on how a node's values might be derived from their childrens' values. In my case, the node values depended on the parent's node values, and on some value changes injected by the visitors, so I did not have to change the parents' version numbers.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: In my case the dependencies are bottom up but the change will already trigger an event on each node on the path to the root. Arne: This bottom up dependency also reduces the utility of your path ID (Also, there could in theory be more than 2 children per node).

Comment: @Nobody: it's up to you to come up with an ID that matches your usecase. By default, a unique ID generated in the node is the simplest, the path ID is a compression scheme in a way, and compression schemes tend to be very specialized.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: The problem is: Any ID that does not contain all information about the subtree is prone to collisions. Therefore, I would need to use the nodes as keys (or a reference to them) to be able to disambiguate. However, this comes with the problems that I have mentioned in my question.

Comment: @Nobody: which collisions ? Can you not use a global 32-bits/64-bits sequence for your tree ?

Comment: @MatthieuM.: The representation of a node depends on all nodes in its subtree (below it) and each node may have additional properties that change the representation and must be taken into account. There cannot be a fixed number of bits that can map them uniquely so collisions can happen.

Comment: @Nobody the IDs do not have to *say* anything about the node. **If** you have a real tree where subtrees are not reused, i.e. if the nodes have only one parent, then a node's address would suffice as unique ID. Of course, on reorganization of the tree you would have to invalidate *all* caches.

Comment: @ArneMertz: It is a real tree because equal subtrees are copies (not references, because the tree itself is not that memory consuming) but it would be nice to cache results only once because the representations can grow large. Reorganization is not so much of a concern here because that does not occur in my application.

Comment: @Nobody if I understand you correctly you would want to give the copied nodes that represent equal subtrees the same ID because their cached values would be the same. I assume that the calculation of the values is done bottom-up. In that case, some representation of the subtree structure might be convenient as ID.